# Lua hierarchy string to table

Tags: lua, lua-table

Is there a way that I can convert a hierarchy string into table form?

Suppose the input is `A.B.C.D`

ouput should be a table which traverses above input: 
`A = {}`
`A.B = {}`
`A.B.C = {}`
`A.B.C.D = {}`

Thanks.

Comment: `local tbl="A.B.C.D"` and `(function(s,k)loadstring(s..('}'):rep(k))()end)((tbl..'.'):gsub('%.','={'))`

Answer (score 5):

The obvious solution would be to parse the string up and construct the hierarchy table from that. But a more clever solution is to let lua do it for you. With a bit of metamagic and function environment manipulation this can be done:

```
dump = require 'pl.pretty'.dump -- convenient table dumper from penlight

function createtable(str)
  local env_mt = {}
  env_mt.__index = function(t, k)
                     rawset(t, k, setmetatable({}, env_mt))
                     return rawget(t, k)
                   end
  local env = setmetatable({}, env_mt)
  local f = loadstring("return "..str)
  setfenv(f, env)
  f()
  return env
end

dump( createtable "A.B.C.D" )
```

this outputs:

```
{
  A = {
    B = {
      C = {
        D = {
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

@greatwolf's answer is right but I prefer the more straightforward approach of "parsing" the string and constructing the table. Less magic, and you do not execute a function loaded from a (possibly) user-defined string, which would be a security issue.

```
local createtable = function(str)
  local top = {}
  local cur = top
  for i in str:gmatch("[^.]+") do
    cur[i] = {}
    cur = cur[i]
  end
  return top
end

(require "pl.pretty").dump(createtable("A.B.C.D"))
```

Comment: Nice. Just note that `A` is not the table returned by createtable, but a field in that table.

Comment: Yes, I copied @greatwolf's output. If you want to return A you just have to skip the first part of the string, e.g. by changing the pattern to `"\.([^.]+)"`.